# Problem while binding DataGridComboBoxColumn in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I am novice in WPF. I have a wpftoolkit datagrid where i am using a combo box as datagridcombox column. I am using a observable collection of Codes for binding the combo box. Below is the collection and its class...

```vb
#Region "Class & Coll"
Public Class CodesColl
    Inherits ObservableCollection(Of Codes)
End Class

Public Class Codes

    Private pCode As String
    Private pDescription As String 

    Public Sub New()
        pCode = String.Empty
        pDescription = String.Empty       
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Property"

    Public Property fldCode() As String
        Get
            Return pCode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            pCode = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property fldDescription() As String
        Get
            Return pDescription
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            pDescription = value
        End Set
    End Property


#End Region
End Class
```

Now what i want achieve is that i need to bind the collection with dropdown in the grid.In my grid i have two columns in first column i have to display the code (fldCode) , and on the selection of the code the next column of the same row will get populated with its description (fldDescription).

My Xaml is something like this:

```
<wpfkit:DataGrid Margin="3" Style="{DynamicResource SimpleDataGrid}" FontWeight="Normal"
 MaxHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource odpExistingCodesColl}}" 
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgCodes" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >                                 
<wpfkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    <wpfkit:DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True">
        <wpfkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                                             
            <DataTemplate>                                                               
                <Image Style="{DynamicResource SimpleImageDelete}"/>
            </DataTemplate> 
        </wpfkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </wpfkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <wpfkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Code" 
    DisplayMemberPath="fldCode" 
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding fldCodes.fldCode}" 
    SelectedValuePath="fldCode"     
    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding fldCodeList}"                                        
    Width="100" x:Name="cbTCodes"  >
    <wpfkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property ="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=odpCodesColl}"/>

        </Style>
        </wpfkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <wpfkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle >
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property ="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=odpCodesColl}"/>
                <Setter Property ="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
        </wpfkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    </wpfkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn>                                                        
    <wpfkit:DataGridTextColumn Width="375" Header="Description" x:Name="tbTCodeDescription" />
</wpfkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</wpfkit:DataGrid>
```

odpExistingCodesColl here is another collection through which i am binding the entire grid and is used for sending the code and its description to but i am facing following problems

1. Unable to display the codes in dropdown.
2. Somehow i manged to do so but it disappears after loosing focus from the combobox.
3. Unable to retrive the description on its selection change as , i am unable to find the event too.

So you guys are requested to help me out asap.. any help will be highly appreciated..
Thanks in Advance 
Amit Ranjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check on [Vincent's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/14/wpf-datagrid-dissecting-the-visual-layout.aspx) for detail information about how to work with Wpf DataGrid(DataGridComboBoxColumn too).

Comment: I have already visited VinSibal but it was not that much relevant. Anywayz thanks for the help